# Get the mouse coordinates inside an JScrollPane

Tags: java, mouse, jscrollpane, coordinate

can someone please tell me how I can get the mouse coordinates when I click inside a JScrollPane? I need the X and the Y coordinate, is that possible?

Comment: you need it when it clicks or you need it when its hovering around the pane ?

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample code attached

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Solution extends JFrame {
    public void init(){

        this.setSize(600,600);
        JScrollPane pane=new JScrollPane();
        this.add(pane);
        setVisible(true);
        pane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {



            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Mouse X="+e.getY()+" Mouse Y="+e.getY());

            }

        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Solution().init();

    }
}
```